# WPF: How to bind to the name property

Tags: wpf, binding

Can i bind to the name property?
This does not seem to work:

```
<TextBlock Name="FordPerfect" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Am i doing something wrong?

**Edit**:
Adding `ElementName=FordPerfect"` solved the issue. What i don't understand is why only binding to `Name` required this while other properties don't.

Note: Moved the second (design) issue to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377072/wpf-multiple-controls-binding-to-same-property) (where i should have placed in the first time...)

Thanks

Comment: It should work. Have you set the DataContext of the element/object correctly? Or have you set it at all?

Comment: If i use a different property (e.g. Margin) it works...

Comment: Hi! Added a new answer which may be a better fit than the accepted one since that relies on specifying the element name.  Using a RelativeSource with a type of 'Self' achieves the same thing but cleaner, and in a more reusable manner as it can also be used in styles should it need to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try this :

```
<TextBlock Name="FordPerfect" 
 Text="{Binding ElementName=FordPerfect, Path=Name, Converter={StaticResource conv}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This way, your TextBlock will be the context of the binding.
If it does not work, watch the Output window, you should find a binding error !

Comment: I'm surprise it worked in the first place with other properties. Basically, Binding need a source. Either you explicitly fix the source or elementName, or you fix the DataContext.

Comment: Here is a good start for an overview of binding : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: About differences between DataContext and Source : http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=6

Comment: What is this Converter named conv? Why can't we just simply bind via the name. All I want is
<Something1 Name="Thing1" />
<Something2 Width="{Binding ElementName=Thing1, Path=ActualWidth}" />

Comment: You may use a converter when the type does not corrrespond. When you need a cast, or a calculation. I don't know why I suggested a converter here, since it's a string put a string property

Comment: Your example reads ActualWidth and put the value inside Width, so it should work without converter.

Answer (score 2):

you could have more easily done this:

```
<TextBlock Name="FordPerfect" 
           Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource conv}, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

As to why: that textbox' DataContext is not automatically the TextBox itself. So binding to `Name` tries to bind to `whateverObjectInDataContext.Name`. So either you set the DataContext beforehand like:

```
<TextBlock Name="FordPerfect" DataContext={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}} 
           Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource conv}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

... or directly set a Source for the Binding

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is a `Binding`, by default, uses the `DataContext` of the element it's used on as its source. However you want the binding source to be the `TextBlock` element itself.

WPF has a class called `RelativeSource` which, as its name implies, sets the source relative to the binding.  One of the relations you can choose is `Self` which does exactly what you want: sets the source of the binding to the element it's used on.

Here's the code:

```
<TextBlock Name="FordPerfect" Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Since you're already setting the source with `RelativeSource`, you don't need to specify `ElementName`.  You also don't need `Mode=OneWay` as a `TextBlock.TextProperty` already defaults to one-way since it's output-only.

Hope this helps!